# How to add an additional CSV Column populated with data from a substring search

Tags: powershell, csv

What I am trying to do is I have a list of servers in the following form serverapp1.dev.domain.com
devserverapp2.domain.com
serverapp3.prod.domain.com

As you can see, the naming is what it is, but What I am trying to do is, to add an additional column that would look into the name of the server and determine that it is app1dev, or app2dev, or app3prod...
I am not good with this, trying

$filePath = "D:\Data\test_raw.csv"

```
$system = "D:\Data\New.csv"

$desiredColumnsSystem =
@{ expression = {$_.'NAME'}; label = 'Key-Hostname:HOSTNAME'}



$regex = '(app1)|(dev)'

Try {
    Write-Log -Message 'Starting Creation of Mashup CSV...'

    Import-Csv $filePath | Select-Object $desiredColumnsSystem -Unique |
    Export-Csv -Path $system –NoTypeInformation

    $size = ((Get-Item $system).length/1KB)
    $lastTouchedDate = (Get-Item $system).LastWriteTime

    Write-Log -Message  "Created the System CSV Successfully !! The size of $system is $size KB and the last write time was $lastTouchedDate"
}

catch
{
    Write-Log -Message $_.Exception.Message -Level Warn
}
```

Comment: your `Select-Object` seems to be trying to create an object from the input CSV that contains ONLY a `.Name` property. if you wan to ADD to the existing props, you must have all those props listed OR use `-Property *` to get them all.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lee_Dailey

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share what I put together, if anyone would have suggestion on how to improve it or if it can help somebody else in the future

```
. D:\Data\BF_Scripts\Write-Log.ps1

$filePath = "D:\Data\System.csv"


$mashup = "D:\Data\Output\AppClusterMashup.csv"

$desiredColumnsSystem =
@{ expression = {$_.'NAME'}; label = 'Key-Hostname:HOSTNAME'}



Try {
    Write-Log -Message 'Starting Creation of the Application Cluster Mashup CSV...'

    Import-Csv $filePath | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.'NAME' -like '*dev*') {
        $Cluster = 'DEVCLUSTER'
    }
    elseif ( $_.'NAME' -like '*prod*' ) {
        $Cluster = 'PRODCLUSTER'
    }
    elseif ( $_.'NAME' -like '*ite*' ) {
        $Cluster = 'ITECLUSTER'
    }

    elseif ( $_.'NAME' -like '*otdr*' ) {
        $Cluster = 'OTDRCLUSTER'
    }
    elseif ( $_.'NAME' -like '*staging*' ) {
        $Cluster = 'STAGINGCLUSTER'
    }
    elseif ( $_.'NAME' -like '*test*' ) {
        $Cluster = 'TESTCLUSTER'
    }
    else {
    $Cluster = ''
    }
    $_
} |


Select-Object $desiredColumnsSystem ,"CLUSTER"| ForEach-Object { $_.CLUSTER = $Cluster; return $_ } |
    Export-Csv -Path $mashup –NoTypeInformation

    $size = ((Get-Item $mashup).length/1KB)
    $lastTouchedDate = (Get-Item $mashup).LastWriteTime

    Write-Log -Message  "Created the Application Cluster Mashup CSV Successfully !! The size of $mashup is $size KB and the last write time was $lastTouchedDate"
}

catch
{
    Write-Log -Message $_.Exception.Message -Level Warn
}
```